# Performance of loading parquet files into case classes in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am assessing the performance of different ways of loading Parquet files in Spark and the differences are staggering.

In our Parquet files, we have nested case classes of the type:

```scala
case class C(/* a dozen of attributes*/)
case class B(/* a dozen of attributes*/, cs: Seq[C])
case class A(/* a dozen of attributes*/, bs: Seq[B])
```

It takes a while to load them from Parquet files.
So I've done a benchmark of different ways of loading case classes from Parquet files and summing a field using Spark 1.6 and 2.0.

Here is a summary of the benchmark I did:

```scala
val df: DataFrame = sqlContext.read.parquet("path/to/file.gz.parquet").persist()
df.count()

// Spark 1.6

// Play Json
// 63.169s
df.toJSON.flatMap(s => Try(Json.parse(s).as[A]).toOption)
         .map(_.fieldToSum).sum()

// Direct access to field using Spark Row
// 2.811s
df.map(row => row.getAs[Long]("fieldToSum")).sum()

// Some small library we developed that access fields using Spark Row
// 10.401s
df.toRDD[A].map(_.fieldToSum).sum()

// Dataframe hybrid SQL API
// 0.239s
df.agg(sum("fieldToSum")).collect().head.getAs[Long](0)

// Dataset with RDD-style code
// 34.223s
df.as[A].map(_.fieldToSum).reduce(_ + _)

// Dataset with column selection
// 0.176s
df.as[A].select($"fieldToSum".as[Long]).reduce(_ + _)


// Spark 2.0

// Performance is similar except for:

// Direct access to field using Spark Row
// 23.168s
df.map(row => row.getAs[Long]("fieldToSum")).reduce(_ + _)

// Some small library we developed that access fields using Spark Row
// 32.898s
f1DF.toRDD[A].map(_.fieldToSum).sum()
```

I understand why the performance of methods using Spark Row is degraded when upgrading to Spark 2.0, since `Dataframe` is now a mere alias of `Dataset[Row]`.
That's the cost of unifying the interfaces, I guess.

On the other hand, I'm quite disappointed that the promise of `Dataset` is not kept: performance when using RDD-style coding (`map`s and `flatMap`s) is worse than when using `Dataset` like `Dataframe` with SQL-like DSL.

Basically, to have good performance, we need to give up type safety.

1. What is the reason for such difference between `Dataset` used as RDD and `Dataset` used as `Dataframe`?
2. Is there a way to improve encoding performance in `Dataset` to equate RDD-style coding and SQL-style coding performance? For data engineering, it's much cleaner to have RDD-style coding.
3. Also, working with the SQL-like DSL would require to flatten our data model and not use nested case classes. Am I right that good performance is only achieved with flat data models?

Answer (score 3):

> What is the reason for such difference between Dataset used as RDD and Dataset used as Dataframe?

To get some insights let's think for a moment about optimizations used by Spark SQL. As far as I am aware there three types of improvements over plain `RDD`:

- execution plan optimizations (projections and selections pushdown, constant folding),
- native (off-heap) memory usage and efficient columnar caching format,
- code generation.

Now the problem is that not all of these techniques are useful outside restricted programming models, like SQL.

For example it is possible to pushdown selections (filters) but projections are quite limited (you cannot really have a part of the object, can you?). Similarly code generation depends on well defined semantics and it is not easy to it applied in general (it is basically a compiler which generates code that can further optimized by JVM).

Finally `sun.misc.Unsafe` is an amazing way to improve performance but it doesn't come for free. While there is a lot of gain here there is also a significant overhead of encoding and decoding.

> working with the SQL-like DSL would require to flatten our data model and not use nested case classes.

Nested structures are not exactly the first class citizens and there are some poorly documented limitations you can still do quite lot here.

> performance of methods using Spark Row is degraded when upgrading to Spark 
>   2.0, since Dataframe is now a mere alias of Dataset[Row]. That's the cost of unifying the interfaces, I guess.

While there have been some performance regression these two pieces of code are simply not equivalent. In 2.0.0+ `DataFrame.map` has different signature than it's 1.x counterpart. If you want to make these two comparable you should convert to `RDD` first:

```
df.rdd.map(row => row.getAs[Long]("fieldToSum")).reduce(_ + _)
```

Comment: I had not delved enough into Spark interfaces to see the difference between `Dataframe.map` interfaces in Spark 1.x and 2.x. Nevertheless, `df.rdd.map(row => row.getAs[Long]("fieldToSum")).reduce(_ + _)` and `df.map(row => row.getAs[Long]("fieldToSum")).reduce(_ + _)` roughly have the same performance. Is there no way to revert to the old mechanism to maintain performance?

Comment: None that I aware of but to be fair I am not sure what is the culprit in this particular case and I cannot really really reproduce such a difference. It could be worth forwarding to dev list though.